# poly crop image python: How to change mask color

Tags: python, opencv, polygon, mask

I'm croping an image with a polygon array, but I need to change the swoed mask color to PINK for another program recognize it as a mask. How to do that?

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import time
    
    img = cv2.imread("teste3.jpg")
    start=time.time()
    height = img.shape[0]
    width = img.shape[1]
    
    mask = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)
    points = np.array([[[692,71],[1386,71],[1617,520],[1617,817],[495,817],[692,520]]])
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, points, (255))
    
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask = mask)
    
    rect = cv2.boundingRect(points) # returns (x,y,w,h) of the rect
    cropped = res[rect[1]: rect[1] + rect[3], rect[0]: rect[0] + rect[2]]
    print(time.time() - start)
    cv2.imshow("cropped" , cropped )
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways are:

- numpy conditional expression (done in 35 ms):

  ```
  pink = (255, 0, 255)
  res = img.copy()
  res[mask==0] = pink
  ```
- cv2 split+bitwises+merge (done in 20 ms):

  ```
  pink = (255, 0, 255)
  whitesheet = np.full_like(mask, 255)
  mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
  channels = cv2.split(img)
  for i in range(len(channels)):
      a = cv2.bitwise_and(whitesheet, channels[i], mask=mask)
      b = cv2.bitwise_and(whitesheet, pink[i], mask=mask_inv)
      channels[i] = cv2.bitwise_or(a, b)
  res = cv2.merge(channels)
  ```